# Suppose $K/F$ is a Galois extension of degree $p^m$. Then there is a chain of extensions $F \subseteq F_1 \subseteq \cdots F_m = K$ each of degree $p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, field-theory, galois-theory, sylow-theory

Suppose $K/F$ is Galois and of degree $p^m$ where $p$ is a prime of course.

Then how can we see that we have an extension $F_0 = F \subsetneq F_1 \subsetneq \cdots \subsetneq F_m = K$ such that $[F_i :F_{i-1}] = p$ for all $i \leq m$.

I wonder if I'm not overcomplicating this- is this merely a combination of the Galois Correspondence and the Sylow theorems?

$Gal(K/F)$ is a $p$ group of order $p^m$. I think the using the Sylow theorems we should be able to find a sequence of subgroups of order $p^{k}$ for each $k \leq m$ and make them nested. Then the corresponding field extensions should have the appropriate degree I believe. But the big problem here is that these subgroups must satisfy normality, which I don't think we can conclude from just the Sylow theorems. That is we may have $G_0 = \{e\} \leq G_1 \leq \cdots \leq G_m = Gal(K/F)$ with $|G_i| = p^i$ but $G_i$ may not be normal in $G_{i+1}$.

Is there a way to ensure normality here? Or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: You sould add somewhere that you want $F_i/F_{i-1}$ to be Galois, as it is not specified anywhere in your post (but I guess you want that since you ar asking about normality)

Answer (score 2):

Finite $p$-groups are super solvable: in fact, you can find  a chain of subgroups $G_0=\{1_G\}\subset \cdots G_i\subset G_{i+1}\subset\cdots \subset G_m=G$ such that each subgroup $G_i$ has order $p^i$ and is normal in $G$ (not only in $G_{i+1}$ !)

The proof is by induction on $m$. The case $m=0$ is clear. Now if $G$ has order $p^{m+1}$, it has non trivial center, so by Cauchy theorem, we may pick $z\in Z(G)$ of order $p$.  Remember that a (normal) subgroup of the quotient may be written as $H/\langle z\rangle$, where $H$ is a (normal) subgroup of $G$ containing $\langle z\rangle $, and that $H$ is unique.

Now apply induction on $G/\langle z\rangle$ to find an appriopriate chain of normal subgroups, and lift it via $G\to G/\langle z\rangle$ to get a chain of subgroups ending on the left by $\langle z\rangle$. To conclude, add the trivial subroup on the left and you are done.

Comment: "Super solvable" = nilpotent.